# Specifying different application names for spring cloud gateway to load balance

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Netflix Eureka for service discovery and spring cloud gateway for load balancing. I want to know, whether there is a method, where I can navigate to any one instance of the microservices registered in eureka by name. For example, if I have 3 services (service-1, service-2, service-3) registered on eureka, and I travel to some path, say localhost:8080/showLB, then it should loadbalance between the 3 services for every call made. Just like HaProxy.

Comment: Are they three different services or instances of the same service?

Comment: 3 different services

Comment: with different api's? I'm unsure how that would work